# How can I fix mt76x2u boot errors?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, boot, kernel-modules

### Problem

Soon after booting my Linux distribution (Arch) I'm getting some errors related to `mt76x2u` module:

```
$ journalctl --boot --priority err
-- Journal begins at Thu 2021-04-01 16:24:56 CEST, ends at Tue 2021-04-13 17:06:36 CEST. --
kwi 13 16:04:44 robert-laptop kernel: mt76x2u 3-2.4.4:1.0: error: MCU resp evt:9 seq:1-0
kwi 13 16:04:44 robert-laptop kernel: mt76x2u 3-2.4.4:1.0: error: MCU resp evt:9 seq:1-0
kwi 13 16:04:44 robert-laptop kernel: mt76x2u 3-2.4.4:1.0: error: MCU resp evt:9 seq:1-0
kwi 13 16:24:06 robert-laptop kernel: mt76x2u 3-2.4.4:1.0: rx urb failed: -71
kwi 13 16:24:06 robert-laptop kernel: mt76x2u 3-2.4.4:1.0: rx urb failed: -71
kwi 13 16:24:06 robert-laptop kernel: mt76x2u 3-2.4.4:1.0: rx urb failed: -71
kwi 13 16:24:06 robert-laptop kernel: mt76x2u 3-2.4.4:1.0: rx urb failed: -71
kwi 13 16:24:06 robert-laptop kernel: mt76x2u 3-2.4.4:1.0: rx urb failed: -71
kwi 13 16:24:06 robert-laptop kernel: mt76x2u 3-2.4.4:1.0: rx urb failed: -71
kwi 13 16:24:06 robert-laptop kernel: mt76x2u 3-2.4.4:1.0: rx urb failed: -71
kwi 13 16:24:06 robert-laptop kernel: mt76x2u 3-2.4.4:1.0: rx urb failed: -71
kwi 13 16:24:06 robert-laptop kernel: mt76x2u 3-2.4.4:1.0: rx urb failed: -71
kwi 13 16:24:06 robert-laptop kernel: mt76x2u 3-2.4.4:1.0: rx urb failed: -71
kwi 13 16:24:06 robert-laptop kernel: mt76x2u 3-2.4.4:1.0: vendor request req:07 off:1134 failed:-71
kwi 13 16:24:06 robert-laptop kernel: mt76x2u 3-2.4.4:1.0: mac specific condition occurred
kwi 13 16:24:06 robert-laptop kernel: mt76x2u 3-2.4.4:1.0: mac specific condition occurred
kwi 13 16:39:33 robert-laptop kernel: mt76x2u 3-2.4.4:1.0: error: MCU resp evt:9 seq:1-0
kwi 13 16:39:33 robert-laptop kernel: mt76x2u 3-2.4.4:1.0: error: MCU resp evt:9 seq:1-0
kwi 13 16:39:33 robert-laptop kernel: mt76x2u 3-2.4.4:1.0: error: MCU resp evt:9 seq:1-0
```

After some web searching it seems `mt76x2u` is probably related to [Xbox Wireless Adapter](https://www.xbox.com/en-US/accessories/adapters/wireless-adapter-windows) I have connected into one of my USB ports.

### Question

1. What do those errors mean?
2. How can I fix them?

Answer (score 1):

A possible fix to get rid of the boot errors is blacklisting `mt76x2u` kernel module. For that you can add `/etc/modprobe.d/no-xbox-wireless-adapter.conf` file with the following contents:

```
# Blacklisting mt76x2u because it gives errors on boot.
# mt76x2u is used by Xbox Wireless Adapter.
blacklist mt76x2u
```

Then you need to regenerate `initramfs` to generated new ramdisk with the module removed. On Arch you do it by running `mkinitcpio -p linux`.